# Exporting specific frame of ListAnimate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, animation, gui-construction, iterators

Imagine I have a certain list of `Graphics`-type objects that I then incorporate into `ListAnimate`

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Graphics[Circle[RandomReal[1, 2], RandomReal[1, 2]]], {j, 20}],
  ImageSize -> Tiny, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Now, I want to define a `Button`, so that, upon clicked, it prints the current frame on `ListAnimate`. How do I do that? I was wondering if it's possible to track the current iterator in a dynamic way, perhaps by accessing the `Animator` within `ListAnimate`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t = Table[Graphics[Circle[RandomReal[1, 2], RandomReal[1, 2]]], 20];
```

We can add a button in `Manipulate` to paste the current content in the next cell:

```
pasteButton = Button[Pane["Paste", ImageSize -> {250, Automatic}, 
     Alignment -> Center],
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell];
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], ToBoxes@#]; 
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell]; 
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents]] &;

Manipulate[t[[i]], 
 {{i, 1}, Range[20], Animator, AnimationRunning -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 250,
  AppearanceElements ->
   {"ProgressSlider", "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
    "PlayPauseButton", "DirectionButton"}},
 Dynamic @ pasteButton[t[[i]]],
 ContentSize -> {250, 200}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Update:** Organize buttons in a row:

```
pasteButton2 = 
  Button[Style["Paste", 10], 
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell];
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], ToBoxes@#];
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents]] &;

Manipulate[t[[i]], 
 Row[{Control @ {{i, 1}, Range[20], Animator, AnimationRunning -> False,
      ImageSize -> 250, 
     AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "FasterSlowerButtons", 
       "PlayPauseButton", "DirectionButton"}}, 
   Dynamic @ pasteButton2[t[[i]]]}], ContentSize -> {300, 200}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to include the "Paste" button as a small button together with the `AppearanceElements`?

Comment: @samwolfe, please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

```
t = Table[Graphics[Circle[RandomReal[1, 2], RandomReal[1, 2]]], 20];
```

You can use [`DynamicSetting`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicSetting.html) and [`EvaluateInPlace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluateInPlace.html) to turn the code into a `Manipulate` object that works like a button to paste the current content in the next cell.

```
DynamicSetting @ Manipulate[t[[i]], 
 {{i, 1}, Range[20], Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}, 
 ContentSize -> {300, 300}, Alignment -> Center]
```

Highlight the code and hit <kbd>`Control`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>. Then, you can paste the current content in the next cell by using <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: What is your screen capture solution?

Comment: @Syed, I am using [ScreenToGIF](https://www.screentogif.com/)

Comment: ,,, and how do you make these buttons? Thanks for both the responses.

Comment: @Syed, you can use the `Edit` button under my post the see how the buttons are made.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, and think about it some more. You don't need both the ListAnimate and Manipulate.

```
ListAnimate[
 t = Table[
   Graphics[
    Circle[RandomReal[1, 2], RandomReal[1, 2]]],
   20
   ],
 ImageSize -> {200, 200},
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 AnimationRunning -> False
 ]
```

I have made a few minor changes. 't' is a table that contains "Graphics" for the 20 frames. You can move t=Table[ ... ] outside the ListAnimate and evaluate it first and later use only t inside the ListAnimate.

OR you could use Manipulate on the table directly..

```
Manipulate[
 t[[i]],
 {{i, 1}, Range[20]},
 ContentSize -> {400, 200},
 ControlType -> Setter
 ]
```

[image]

Investigate other ControlType options. I hope it helps.

Comment: Using `ControlType -> Animator` in `Manipulate` you get the same look as `ListAnimate` , _and_ you can use the $\bigoplus$ menu to paste the code for the current frame in the next cell (+1)